# Obtaining API key for embedding Google Maps in Web Site

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-embed

Struggling to do something that appears to be quite simple. I would like to obtain an API Key so I can embed a Google Map into a web page. I've followed the directions found on this page,  https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/embed/guide

which are as follows:

1) Visit the APIs Console at Google Developers Console and log in with your Google Account.

2) Click the Services link from the left-hand menu.

3) Activate the Google Maps Embed API service.

4) Click the API Access link from the left-hand menu. Your API key is available from the API Access page, in the Simple API Access section. Maps API applications use the Key for browser apps.

The problem is that when I visit that page there is no "services" link on the left-hand menu, nor is there an "API Access" link. There is a menu item that reads "API & Auth", which has four sub-menus (APIs, Credentials, Consent Screen and Push). When I click on the APIs link an API Library appears, which is broken down into several sections. Under the Google Map APIs section, I click on the Google Maps Embed API link. There, I can choose between Overview, Usage and Quotas, and that's it.

So, where can I obtain this Key? I can't find a link, or even information, that references it.

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Kind regards,

Mark

Answer (score 0):

According to this: [Google maps api sign up](https://developers.google.com/maps/signup) I don't think you need an API key any more for V3 of google maps API. However, you can still get one to track your maps usage. I've just read all that from the link.

That link was last updated May 28th, 2015, so it must be fairly recent.

Comment: Hi Hackjob, well still not having any luck:(  I have followed the instructions on this page (https://support.google.com/maps/answer/3544418?hl=en) but can't find any link that reads "embed" or "share". I have asked a friend who uses Google Chrome, and still no luck. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

It's under "APIs and auth"->"Credentials"
Check out this documentation:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key#key

1. Create or select a project.
2. Click Continue to Enable the API.
3. Go to Credentials to get a **Browser key** (and set the API Credentials).
4. To prevent quota theft, secure your API key following best practices.
5. (Optional) Enable billing. See Usage Limits for more information.